# ASP.NET MVC Viewmodel trouble

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I've already started similar [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484852/asp-net-mvc-how-to-transfer-more-than-one-object-to-view-method), but still didn't find final solution...
So here I am with new one :) ... I'm developing NerdDinner from scratch and now I came to point where I define DinnerViewModel.
Following [these instructions](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/04/13/asp.net-mvc-tip-50-ndash-create-view-models.aspx) (starting from **Listing 5**) I came to this:

```
namespace Nerd.Controllers
{

    // View Model Classes  

    public class DinnerViewModel
    {
        public DinnerViewModel(List<Dinner> dinners)
        {
            this.Dinners = dinners;
        }

        public List<Dinner> Dinners { get; private set; }

    } 

    public class DinnerController : Controller
    {
        private DinnerRepository dinnerRepository = new DinnerRepository();

        ....

        public ActionResult NewDinners()
        {
            // Create list of products  
            var dinners = new List<Dinner>();
            dinners.Add(new Dinner(/*Something to add*/));

            // Return view  
            return View(new DinnerViewModel(dinners));
        }


    }
}
```

Also, the `Dinner` table in this new version of NerdDinner is a bit shortened (it contains of `DinnerID`, `Title`, `EventDate` and `Description` fields).

No matter what I try to add here `dinners.Add(new Dinner(/*Something to add*/));` I always get following error

> Error 1   'Nerd.Model.Dinner' does not
>   contain a constructor that takes '1'
>   arguments C:\Documents and
>   Settings\ilija\My Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2008\Projects\Nerd\Nerd\Controllers\DinnerController.cs   150 25  Nerd

Because I'm total beginner in C# and generally OOP, I have no idea what to do here... I suppose I need to declare a constructor, but how and where exactly?

Thanks,
Ile

Comment: If you are new to C# and Programming in general, I strongly suggest not to start out with something as elaborated as MVC applications. You must understand the underlying concepts first. You can still make a lot of progress very fast, but don't start in the middle of the game.

I've been down that road - it can be frustrating and extremely inefficient. This is really just meant as good advice, I don't want to discourage you.

Comment: I know what you mean, but I got my undergraduate thesis to build CMS in ASP.NET MVC, so when jumping from (procedural) PHP to OOP C# I wasn't complete beginner in programming, only this OOP is making troubles for now :) Thanks for advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to initialize values in new Dinner object, use this construction

```
dinners.Add(new Dinner() { Title = "DinnerTitle", Description = "DinnerDescription" });
```

Comment: This is it! I was trying all the time with normal brackets, never got it on my mind to try curly brackets. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The exception message says it all. Your `Dinner` object doesn't have a constructor that takes 1 argument. So you cannot do this :

```
new Dinner(someVariable)
```

Because there is no method in the `Dinner` class that lets you create a dinner object with one argument.

Comment: so I need to create new (I suppose partial) class called Dinner.cs and create a constructor method?

Comment: @ile, Either you have to create a constructor for Dinner class that accepts 1 argument, or you have to use an existing constructor of it while creating your ViewModel.

Comment: LukLed gave me the answer I was looking for. I don't know exactly what you meant with this existing constructor

Comment: @ile, I think it would be a lot better if you first followed a tutorial on the C# language because otherwise you might find it difficult to understand ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: I have already, but in such short period I've read many tutorials so I have a big mess in my head. This requires a LOT of practice

Answer (score 1):

If you've been following the nerd dinner "tutorial" you've probably used Linq2Sql and the default generated code define Dineer with parameterless constructor (method called 'Dinner()').

Instead you can use properties to set the object's values:

```
Dinner dinner = new Dinner;
dinner.Title = "My dinner";
dinner.Description ="...";
// etc.
```

Comment: I've been following nerd dinner tutorial, all to the "Tests" section, but like I said, I'm totally new here and I couldn't catch it all from the first. There are some things differently done than I would like to...

Comment: I treid this one before, but then I cannot pass the dinner object like this: return View(new DinnerViewModel(dinner));